# Share Internal File

Tags: android, file, android-intent, android-contentprovider

I have two apps, a provider app (A) and a consuming app (B).

In app A I save a zip file in my internal files directory and use a file provider to share it.
In app B I receive the intent and try to read from its uri.

The problem I'm facing is that I try to set a custom action (intent.setAction("custom_action")) in the intent from app A but when I try to read uri I get a security exception. Setting action to Intent.ACTION_SEND works ok. Is it possible to share an internal file with a custom action intent?

Comment: If B receives the provider uri then i see no reason why not.

Comment: Trying to set exported "true" for the provider also throws exception.